# Converting String to DOM

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

My Ajax functions gives me HTML-Elements as String back, and this String I want to append in my Document as DOM Element.

Something like

```
parentNode.appendChild(responseText);
```

What will be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
parentNode.innerHTML += responseText;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use innerText to do it

Comment: Cant use innerText to append DOM since it will append it as TEXT. He must use innerHTML to append that string as HTML (DOM)! Since you are new no -1, but in future...

Answer (score 0):

There can be more possible cases. You should clarify a bit.

1. If you get a string that should be an object and it's not existing yet, then you should use this: `var tempObj = document.createElement("yourString");` then you can just use `tempObj` to handle it.
2. If you get a string that is the name or ID of an existing object, then use: `var tempObj = document.getElementByName("yourString");`

or

```
var tempObj = document.getElementById("yourString");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM methods this library provides, for example the insert() or update() method:

```
$('parentId').insert(yourString);
```

or

```
$('parentId').update(yourString);
```

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/insert/

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/update/

Note that innerHTML is not standarized yet, so using prototype, you can be sure those methods are cross browser compatible.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The simple way for converting String to DOM and vice versa is presented on this link:

http://famulatus.com/ks/programming/java/item/335-convert-xml-dom-to-string-and-string-to-xml-dom.html

Comment: The link doesn't open for me. But telling from the URL, it's about Java. The OP asked for a JavaScript solution.